# Animated science TV show

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I'm trying to find the name of an animated TV show (series) for kids that revolved around science.

The main characters where two kids (girl and boy) and this small flying "pixie" which looked like a little girl with long orange hair and her hair was actually her arms (so the sides of her hair ended with hair folded in the shape of hands).

Throughout the show the three of them learned about science and went on space adventures.

I watched it in the early 90s, but it was probably made in the 80s (we usually got TV show several years late).

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: @LogicDictates Thanks for the question, I added that info to the question.

Comment: *"her hair was actually her arms"* - Huh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Miimu Iro Iro Yume no Tabi](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MiimuIroIroYumeNoTabi)* is a likely candidate.

[image: Splash image for Miimu Iro Iro Yume no Tabi showing Miimunote and the children]

> *Miimu Iro Iro Yume no Tabi* (*Miimu: The Various Dream Journeys*) is a 1983 educational cartoon made by Nippon Animation and aired on the TBS network, similar in many ways to the contemporary *Once Upon a Time... Man* and, to a lesser extent, *Superbook*. Every week a strange creature called Miimunote  is summoned out of a personal computer to narrate the history of an invention or scientific discovery. In the first series, set in the "present day" (for 1983), she is called on by a pair of constantly quarreling siblings, from the second series and onward, set about a generation in the future (again, from 1983), she appears to the members of a Little League baseball team.
>
> The second series introduces, as a regular part of the setting, something it calls "the INS" (short for "Information Network System") — in other words, the Internet — the depiction of which, despite a few Jetsons-esque flourishes, hits far more often than it misses; indeed, it's quite jarringly uncanny to watch it now.

I found it by browsing through TV Tropes entries for [Prehensile Hair](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PrehensileHair).

### Show Intro

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for that cartoon for a while. It didn't help that Mimi was translated as Jeanie in my country.

Comment: Thank you! And what a clever way to find it!